# Проблема с запуском сервера Django (PyCharm)

Tags: django, pycharm

!НОВИЧОК! Нужна помощь по поводу PyCharm. 3 раза нормально запускал проект. После перезагрузки компа перестал перезапускать. Пытался переименовать в Python и удалять. Без толку. Помогите кто сталкивался!
Кому не сложно ответьте в вк https://vk.com/lucker1998

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так проверьте корректность написания первой строки файла...

Answer (score 0):

Первая строка ([шебанг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix))) файла `manage.py` некорректна. Исправьте её на:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Именно такую строку создаёт в файле команда `startproject`. Предположу, что Вы случайно её изменили.